# How do I check if a given number is an Armstrong number or not?

Tags: string, if-statement, input, integer, temp

I want to check number given by the person is an Armstrong number or not.

I try to check number given by the person is an Armstrong number or not. And I expect the code to perform well.

Answer (score 0):

number = int(input("Enter a number: "))

order = len(str(number))

sum = 0

temp = number

while temp > 0:

```
digit = temp % 10

sum += digit ** order

temp //= 10
```

if number == sum:

```
print(number ,"is an Armstrong number")
```

else:

```
print(number ,"is not an Armstrong number")
```

Comment: Please do an introduction on what the Armstrong number is (the answer is there). Say what language and language version you are using.

Comment: Please do an introduction on what the Armstrong number is (the answer is there). Say what language and language version you are using.